# How to get the XML output from a Service on a remote connection

Tags: c#, xml, service, runtime, remoting

I wrote a Mail service to retrieve mail from different mail accounts. Then i have a different program which should have the function of a live dashboard that displays the information retrieved from the Mail Service...

I want to capture the output of the Mail Service into XML and call it over the remote connection to the dashboard. To display the results of the Service run.

How do i create the XML during runtime in an object and display on my dashboard?

Please guide me into the right direction....